# js Canvas picture not showing up?

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I have this code that is supposed to display a simple image of a bowling man. 
The problem? He does not appear.
Here is the code:

```
<script>
function initCanvas()
{

        var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');

        var bowling1 = new Image();
        bowling1.src = 'img/bowling1.png';
        bowling1.addEventListener("load", function(){ctx.drawImage(bowling1,0,0)}, false) 
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    initCanvas();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
```

This is a picture of the folder my code and "bowling1" pic is in.
[Picture of the folder (testHolder.html is the file my code runs on)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27PmG.png)

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. Make sure check that your source is correct?

Comment: Yes, I will add a pic of my folder structure.

Comment: Try changing this line `bowling1.src = 'img/bowling1.png';` to `bowling1.src = 'ibowling1.png';` from what I can see you don't have an img folder so you don't need the "img/"